# Show that $\max(\mathrm{Re} (\exp(it)\cdot z) = |z| $

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I need to show that $\max(\mathrm{Re} (\exp(it)z) = |z| $, with $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Therefore I have calculated $\exp(it) = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$. If we write $z=  a+bi$, then
$$
\mathrm{Re}(\exp(it)z) = \mathrm{Re}(\exp(it)(a+bi) = a\cdot \mathrm{Re}(\cos t + i\sin t) + b\cdot \mathrm{Re}(i\cos t - \sin t) = 
$$
$$
a\cdot \cos t - b \cdot \sin t
$$

To calculate the maximum, I figured to set the derivative equal to zero, so
$$
-a \cdot \sin t - b\cdot \cos(t) = 0
$$

From here, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: $$(a\cos t+b\sin t)^2+(a\sin t-b\cos t)^2=a^2+b^2\implies a\cos t+b\sin t\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: And can anyone make a sketch of this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

We can always write $z=\left|z\right|e^{i\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then $Re\left(e^{-i\alpha}z\right)=\left|z\right|$ and  $Re\left(e^{it}z\right)\leq\left|e^{it}z\right|=\left|z\right|$
for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$.